# What's the correct way to use Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the correct way to use fragments? Should i use only one FragmentActivity per interface or use a unique FragmentActivity for all interfaces?

My app is quite simple: it has 4 distinct interfaces, a fixed options menu on top and i only show contextual menu in a interface called 'actions'.

I was thinking to use only one FragmentActivity with an area where i could switch between fragments. Is it a good practice or should i keep one FragmentActivity per interface?

By now, i'm using one FragmentActivity per interface but when i change ( start ) FragmentActivity, it looks like that is creating a new object and my app blinks before open the new activity.

Thank in advance.

edit:

Here is a drawing of my app: http://postimg.org/image/mvxyk2527/

Comment: Could you please show some drawings / images showing what you would like to achieve? Both approaches are valid, but which one you should use depends on what you want. Generally, you start a new activity when the user needs to feel like he's going to a new place, or another level of detail - an exception to this is when using a navigation drawer. If you want tabs or a spinner, you are going to use multiple fragments in one activity.

Comment: Check the link that i put on question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a lot of personal preference and requirement really. I'm not a big believer of the "correct way" concept, if you achieve your goal then it's not wrong, but there may be a nicer way to do it.

For me it would depend on how many nested fragments each FragmentActivity handles. If you have a tree of nested fragments you can get into a mess with nested fragment stacks, etc.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Personally, if I'm writing an application with lots of fragments I tend to have a single Activity which makes navigation a bit more manageable with a single Fragment stack as using multiple FragmentActivity instances will use multiple fragment stacks.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

You could consider the ViewPager approach which is great if you want to use a tabular and swiping navigation. Although if you have heavy scrollable content views I would be hesitant as for some individuals multi-directional gesture interfaces can be quite frustrating.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

If your code is clean, manageable and not leaking references then I would probably stick with what you have and wouldn't waste your time re-factoring it.

Comment: But i have something frustating in my navigation: when i start new activity, it blinks before open the new activity and i lose the previous changes that i have done. To fix it, i need to put a new validation on each ''onCreate()'' to do the changes again. I think that this validation should be in a single point of application and i don't like to replicate it for each FragmentActivity. Maybe i could do it in my class BaseActivity ( a class that extends FragmentActivity and is extended for others FragmentActivity ) but i would like to avoid that blink/flash between each FragmentActivity

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this "blink" and loss of changes?

It does sound like you've got a bit too much going on in the UI when you're switching Activities. You may want to consider moving some of your processing to a thread if you can. If not you may want to consider an interstitial activity (stepping stone) to create a cleaner transition between activities.

I usually do create my own wrappers for my fragments and activities and have a tree structure of wrappers depending on required functionality to reduce redundant code.

Comment: Buddy, first of all .. excellent explanation!!! I've started refactoring my code to move some code to AsyncTask and implement some Runnables. When i say "blink" is something like "close" and "open". I see my current activity close and open the new one....an example of it: if i change the option icon before call "startActivity()", when starts the new activity, the option icon isn't the new one that i've set, it's the default.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain it properly. In your case, you must use one FragmentActivity that includes fragments. You must create one fragment per interface and commit (exchange) when the user clicks on the menu. This may be an example of the structure of the project:

Java Classes:

- MainActivity.class (extends FragmentActivity)
- Interface1Fragment.class (extends Fragment)
- Interface2Fragment.class (extends Fragment)
- Interface3Fragment.class (extends Fragment)
- Interface4Fragment.class (extends Fragment)

Layouts:

- act_main.xml, frg_inter1, frg_inter2, frg_inter3 and frg_inter4.

In MainActivity and act_main.xml, you must create a tabhost o navigationDrawer for the menu and implement a method that allows to switch between fragments. Later, in each fragment you must implement the interface functionality.

Some code:

- MainActivity:

  ```
  public class ActMain extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
  }


  private void createMenu() {
      //you can create a menu with tabhost or navigation drawer
  }


  // replace a fragment
  public void replaceFragment(Fragment launchFragment) {
      FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();        
      ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, launchFragment).commit();
  }
  }
  ```
- A Fragment:

  ```
  public class Interface1Fragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_inicio, container, false);
      return rootView;
  }
  }
  ```
- MainActivity.xml

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <!-- Main content -->

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0" />

  <!-- Left Navigation Drawer -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:background="@color/black_actionbar"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:onClick="emptyOnClick"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
    /LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  ```
- In fragments xml files you must design your interfaces.

Comment: Great Explanation! For now, fragments does more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you should just change fragments, not restart the fragment activity if that part is gonna stay the same and work the same.
You should just switch between fragments like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

or like this if you are supporting API < 14

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Note : remove addToBackStack(null) if you dont want to go back to previously loaded fragment onBackPressed

Comment: SupportFragments are only for backwards compatibility, given that the current baseline version is 15 this responses are getting a bit stale.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently working on a project with min sdk 10.. I have edited the answer to point out both ways

Comment: Ouch, I feel your pain.

Comment: Its okay, i like it hardcore :P